# groovyfx multiple scenes

Tags: groovy, javafx, groovyfx

I'm trying to implement multipage application with groovyfx and i'm stuck with the scene changing.
Suppose i have the following code:

```
start {
  stage(id: 'stageId', title: 'sometitle'){
      scene(id:'scene1'){
          button(text:'goto scene 2', onAction: {/* i guess i should do something here` */})
      }
      scene(id:'scene2'){
          label(text:'this is scene 2')
      }
  }
}
```

what should i put to button's action to be able to go to scene 2?

Comment: does `stageId.scene = scene2` work?

Comment: i works! thx! i had some experience with groovyswingbuilder, but this looks like a complete magic to me.

Comment: @tim_yates unfortunately i cannot answer my own question

Comment: Added as an answer, I just wanted to check in comments first as I don't currently have a groovyfx setup to test it with :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
stageId.scene = scene2
```

Behind the scenes, that will get the element with the id `stageId` (the main `stage`), and then call `setScene( scene2 )` (where `scene2` is the id of the second scene)

Hope this explains it :-)